# How Salesforce executes a flow on a record triggered plus subflow vs only record triggered

Tags: bulkification, order-of-execution, recordtriggeredflow, subflow, flowsupport

I was wondering if someone here could help me have a bit more clarity over a behavior I'm seeing when executing flows in SF.
I need to call a subflow from a record-triggered flow to execute some actions, however I'm seeing it's behaving differently when I do so vs when I run the actions directly from the record-triggered flow.

Here's a simplification of what I'm trying to achieve:

My flow is first searching for a Case record with the following subject "Testing098", then it gets to a decision where if the previous Get records element Is Null = true, it determines that the Case record does not exist and creates it in the next step, however if it does exist, the flow ends.

I've tried this same flow on both a record-triggered flow and a record-triggered flow that calls an autolaunched flow with my logic

[image]

---

---

[image]

[image]

If I edit a case both flows get triggered and create the "Testing098" Case just fine.
The differences however, start when I edit more than one case in bulk.

If I edit 3 cases in bulk the Recordtriggered-only flow creates only **one** "Testing098" Case. But the Recordtriggered plus autolaunched flows create **three** "Testing098" Cases.

My question here is, how SF executes this kind of flows?, I understand it tries to bulkify the elements that allow to do so. Is it that in the recordtriggered-only flow SF understands that there's a decision dependent on the get records element and doesn't bulkify that part?, and in the Recordtriggered plus autolaunched doesn't see the sub-flow contents and just bulkifies it for the three Case updates?

Comment: I'm surprised by your assertion that the Record-triggered flow creates only one `Testing098` because the Get Records element is bulkified and only 1 SOQL query is executed which would not find the `Testing098`. Are you sure the bulk edit of 3 records is a true single transaction and not three transactions (as the 2nd and 3rd would see that `Testing098` already existed

Comment: Hi cropredy! Yes, pretty sure, I used the same approach for both tests, an updat operation using salesforce inspector with the same batch size. Will make a second test later today but I’m pretty sure I did it the same way in both cases

Comment: Hi again cropredy.
I have to apologize, I'm not sure why last time I got that behavior but you're right, in both cases SF bulkifies the records update in the same way. My only guess of what could have happened the first time I tried is that I modified an automation I already have to include this, I didn't use the simplification shown in my question, maybe that had something to do with how SF handled the operation. I'm ansering my own question with my finidings, thanks!

Comment: I'm investigating on a way of avoiding this. Will answer myself once I find how to do so, to include it here, but any suggestions you may have will be very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion that the Record-triggered flow creates only one `Testing098` Case is not correct.

- The Record-triggered flow Get Records element `Find Case record testing098` is bulkified per the [Flow Bulkification doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_bulkification.htm&type=5)
- Hence, your test must have inadvertently submitted not 1 transaction with 3 records, but three transactions. Thus, transaction 2 would discover that transaction 1 had created `Testing098`

Now, your general problem is how to keep multiple interviews in the same transaction from creating three `Testing098`

- Since each Flow Interview runs in "parallel", the interviews don't talk to each other nor are aware of what the other is doing.
- The common solution to this is to delegate the record creation to an invocable Apex.

The invocable Apex is bulkified and would receive a collection argument of dimension equal to the number of flow interviews in the transaction that reached that Apex action Flow element.

Thus, the invocable can examine using collection operators and `for` loops whether the request to build a Case record is duplicated. The invocable can then de-duplicate the request and create only unique Cases.

Just remember that if the invocable returns values back to the Flow that there has to be 1 result element per request element with `result[i]` corresponding to `request[i]`